# Select top1 with Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, unit-of-work

Actually I’m working with Linq and UOW (unit of work), and I'm doing all of the easy access to bbdd with linq. I know that if I want to get the first row of one table, I can do this:

```
int test4 = (from p 
             in uow.ProductR.context.product 
             where p.Id == 1715 select p.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

That will execute this in SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[product] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 1715 = [Extent1].[Id]
```

My questions is, can I do the same with LINQ to object with the generic repositories of my UOW? I mean, when I execute

```
int test2 = uow.ProductR.Get(p => p.Id == 1715).Select(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or

```
var test3 = uow.ProductR.Get(p => p.Id == 1715).Select(p => new { p.Id });
```

In SQL Server I get:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
FROM [dbo].[product] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1715 = [Extent1].[Id]
```

Of course, with the second way, when the database has 500k rows, it will be slow. (I have more columns, not only 2)

Edited: Here is the Class with the GET declarations

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    internal contextEntities context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(contextEntities context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).AsQueryable();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I have explained well.

Comment: how is the method `Get` implemented ? this statement `uow.ProductR.Get(p => p.Id == 1715).Select(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault();` should use `SELECT  TOP 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Get` needs to return an `IQueryable`, not an `IEnumerable` as it does now. Then, the argument to `Get` becomes useless as well because the caller can just do `Get().Where(...)`. The API surface becomes cleaner because you can delete the argument.

But you are losing control in what way the database is queried. I assume you are doing a repository for testing purposes (if not it's probably a bad choice to have one). Testing the queries that are executed this way becomes harder.

Comment: That's the problem. I had not seen that damn IEnumerable.


The above code is test, but currently I have several projects with the UOW pattern implemented correctly, and these projects are working well, projects that there are between 50 and 400 people online at the same time. (Projects with 5 layers, front,back, application, dal ...)
I do not understand why you say that may not be a right choice. I need to read and inform me of something?

Thank you

Comment: I can answer better with more information. Why did you add a repository (as opposed to just using EF directly)?

Comment: I have the EF which is managing by UOW. So when I need data from the frontend, I access the Dal where I do LINQ queries on the UOW.

That would be the simplified example of the process that I have now.

Comment: *Why* are you using a repository? EF already is a repository and implements UOW.

Comment: I guess when I started using it I did not know enough about them. Probably take it off in new projects and EF6 MVC5

Comment: OK if you don't really understand the choice and trade-offs it's likely a waste of time. Think about whether your project would lose anything if you just deleted the repository source code.

Answer (score 0):

Returning an IQueryable will give you greater flexibility, but it also exposes the possibility of casual modification of queries you've defined in your repository.  If you want to provide a standard mechanism for someone using your repository to return the top N rows, you could add some additional optional properties (note that Take, in conjunction with Skip, is a useful mechanism if you also want to allow paging via your repository without creating separate mechanism or exposing the underlying IQueryable).

You could change your Get method signature to something like this:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = "", int? maxResults = null)
```

Then in your Get method (this should be refactored, but you get the idea):

```
    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return maxResults.HasValue() ? orderBy(query).Take((int)maxResults).ToList() : orderBy(query).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return maxResults.HasValue() ? query.take((int)maxResults).ToList() : query.ToList();
    }
```

Note that your call to AsQueryable() should not be necessary since both IOrderedQueryable and IQueryable implement IEnumerable.  Instead, call ToList() in order to materialize the result set so that it executes.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean me but my main problem was not only obtain 1 line, if not, the query that is executed in database was not exactly what I wanted to run in LINQ(so it was inefficient). It returned more columns than wanted

Thank you